# Filtering in a table - Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba, object, variables

I am trying to do a simple filetering of dates in a table to make it ascending order and there is some issue that I cannot get over. I keep getting Runtime error '91' Object variable or With block variable not set.

```
Range("A4:H4").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet0").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A4"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

Do you see the problem?

Comment: The problem @Gary's Student sees with your code is that Sheet0 may not be the one on which you made the selection and set the autofilter. Hence there is no AutoFilter object on Sheet0. But you wouldn't ever encounter such a problem if you would refrain from using the Select to convert an existing Range object to a Selection object (which VBA uses as a substitute for a Range object). `Worksheets("Sheet0").Range("A4:H4").Autofilter` perfectly replaces your first two lines and avoids the error.

Comment: Besides, you can't use AutoFilter to sort the sequence of your dates. That will require a Sort action.